# Access VBA SQL Update - Too few Parameters expected 1

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am new to access VBA.

I am trying to add 1 to all numbers in a field that are equal or greater than the value in text box `[TP_Bld_OrderNum_Txt]`.

This is my code:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE TP_Matrix " & _
      "SET TP_Matrix.Order_" & Me.TP_Bld_TP_Cbo & " = TP_Matrix.Order_" & Me.TP_Bld_TP_Cbo & "+1 " & _
      "WHERE TP_Matrix.Order_" & Me.TP_Bld_TP_Cbo & ">= Me.TP_Bld_OrderNum_Txt"
```

I get this error:

> too few parameters expected 1

I believe it relates to the text box value.

If I replace `Me.TP_Bld_OrderNum_Txt` with a number, the query works fine.

I have the text box set up as a number.

Why doesn't it recognize its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided `Me.TP_Bld_OrderNum_Txt` as a literal (as a fixed string) and not its value:
`& ">= Me.TP_Bld_OrderNum_Txt"`

Try this instead:
`& " >= " &  Me.TP_Bld_OrderNum_Txt.Value`

Also, it is a good practice to use `.Value` to explicitely use the value of the control.